# convert http json response to a custom class

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am newbie in Laravel & Php.  I have a simple question to ask.

I use Larave's [Http client](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client) to fetch data from another service. After I got response successfully, I access one attributes, let's call it `foo`.  In JSON response it looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": "abc",
  "bar": "abc123"
}
```

My code:

```
$response = Http::post('http://another-service.com/data', [
    'user_id' => 'Steve'
]);

$responseObject = $response->throw()->object();

$value = $responseObject->foo
```

I can access the value from  `$response` e.g. `$responseObject->foo`.  I have no problem here.

But my code analytics tool (PhpStan) warns that `Access to an undefined property object::foo`. I understand why it complains, because the `responseObject` is just an `object`, its attributes are unclear.

I would like to have custom class which can map to the response json but I don't want to use Eloquent because the json object doesn't need to map to database model. What is the right way to achieve what I need?

I tried:

```
class MyData
{
  public string foo;
  public string bar;
}
```

Then :

```
$responseObject = (MyData) $response->throw()->object();
```

But it doesn't work. (I am a Java background)

Comment: As some point you have to access an undefined property if you are doing that with objects. eg. new MyData($responseObject->foo, $responseObject->bar); if you set em through the constructor. Alternative to avoid getting the errors, you could convert you object to an array, an access it like so. This will not trigger the type checks as arrays can't be defined as such.

Comment: But `$responseObject->foo, $responseObject->bar` already yields the same error, no matter to where you pass it. And about covert object to an array, could you please provide a code snippet to illustrate?

Comment: as said if you want to use objects to wrap into your other object, you can not avoid having an undefined property error. Is it larastan you are using?

Comment: Yes. Now I changed to array (I didn't know such option), the error is gone. Thanks.

Comment: Added that as an answer hope you will accept it

Answer (score 0):

To avoid `Larastan` erroring you can either change the data to an array. Luckily PHP can convert between object and array, with only a typehint.

```
$yourArray = (array) $yourObject;
$yourObject = (object) $yourArray;
```

Another solution, i'm not certain on, is typehinting objects to `stdClass`. But github / laracasts issues indicating that change the type to `stdClass`, could also help the problem.

```
/** @var \stdClass $responseObject **/ 
$responseObject = $response->throw()->object();
```

Comment: The way how I solved the problem is `$response->throw()->json()`